# Fastest way to take screenshot of a window

Tags: python, windows, screenshot

```
def take_screenshot(hwnd):

    left, top, right, bot = win32gui.GetClientRect(hwnd)
    #left, top, right, bot = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    width = right - left
    height  = bot - top

    wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    dcObj=win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
    cDC=dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
    dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, width, height)
    cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
    cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (width, height), dcObj, (0, 0), win32con.SRCCOPY)
    im = dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
    img = np.frombuffer(im, dtype='uint8')
    img.shape = (height,width,4)
    cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    dcObj.DeleteDC()
    cDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, wDC)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())
    return img[:,:,:3]
```

I'm using this code at the moment. Is there any way to make it faster= I want to be able to capture 1080 at 60 fps live. Can I use my gpu for this problem? I have gtx 1070.

Comment: You're not going to be able to capture 1080p60 using Python, I'm afraid. Since you mention you have an Nvidia card, you may want to look into something like https://developer.nvidia.com/capture-sdk .

Comment: `from mss import mss` combined with multiprocessing. Each saved screenshot is ~114ms on my machine so with 8+ cores you should achieve the desired rate

Comment: 1 s / 114 ms equals approximately 8.77 FPS, not anywhere near 60, @AlexanderMcFarlane...

Comment: *so with 8+ cores you should achieve the desired rate* so it's about 70fps minus a few for running whatever software you're running I think it's fair to assume 60

Comment: Can I use mss to capture one window for example a calculator window. I want to use it because I want to use the computer while it capturing so it will be in background capturing. My code work because I can just give hwnd